# How to add CPUs to OpenBSD in VirtualBox post-install?

Tags: virtualbox, openbsd

Whenever I install OpenBSD in VirtualBox, I need to set CPU count prior to install, as changing the count later won't make the new cores visible. Is there a command I could run that would reset this count and re-probe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, OpenBSD installs two kernels: `bsd.sp` and `bsd.mp`.  The first for single processor (`sp`) machines, the second for multiprocessor machines (`mp`).  The installer selects which is more appropriate and installs it as `/bsd`, which will then be booted by default.  The other will also be installed (as either `/bsd.sp` or `/bsd.mp`), so it will be available, but not booted by default.

If you only had one CPU when you installed OpenBSD, it will have detected your VM as an `sp` machine, renamed `/bsd.sp` into `/bsd`, so that this boots by default, and left the `mp` kernel as `/bsd.mp`.  If you really want to make sure which is which, `strings` will show you:

```
# strings /bsd.mp | grep ^OpenBSD
...
OpenBSD 6.9-current (GENERIC.MP) #12: Mon May 10 14:33:52 MDT 2021

# strings /bsd | grep ^OpenBSD
...
OpenBSD 6.9-current (GENERIC) #12: Mon May 10 14:22:32 MDT 2021
```

So a vanilla multiprocessor kernel will be named `GENERIC.MP` and a single processor kernel will be named just `GENERIC`. You can see which you are currently running using `sysctl kern.osversion`.

If you want to boot a different kernel, just enter it at the boot prompt:

```
boot> boot /bsd.mp
```

And the multiprocessor kernel will be booted.  You can then check your `dmesg` to see everything is working as planned (i.e. a `GENERIC.MP` kernel was booted and multiple `cpu*` lines show up).

If you want to make this the new default, just rename `/bsd` to `/bsd.sp` and then rename `/bsd.mp` to `/bsd` (or change `/etc/boot.conf`).

Comment: Thank you @zé-loff, this is a really elaborate answer! I did indeed just have one CPU in those cases where I forgot to increase the count, so it's very likely the case I had.

Comment: I don't seem to have a /bsd.mp kernel on 7.4, installed on a single-core VM.

Comment: @rsaxvc `bsd.mp` isn't available on some architectures (e.g. armv7). Or perhaps it wasn't selected when the installer asked what kernels and file sets should be installed. You can get it from any mirror, if needed.

Comment: This was on AMD64. I re-ran the installer, bsd.mp is now removed from the checklist when installing with only one CPU.